# How to write Mule console output in a Text File

Tags: mule, esb

How to write a Mule Console Output to a text file. i am not able to see the full console output for big batch runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a log4j properties file into your main/resources directory, this log4j.xml file will do the trick

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
  <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
  <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

 <appender name="file-appender"
        class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="file" value="path_to_your_log_file_here.log" />
<param name="append" value="true" />
<param name="threshold" value="debug" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>

<root>
<level value="file-appender" />
<appender-ref ref="file-appender" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried adding this in a log4j xml and copied into the main/resources directory then tried running the flow. but no luck :( the log was still not writing to the file i specified.

Comment: Can you share your log4j and the logging componenet of your flow?

Comment: Be sure to use log4j2.xml if you are using Mule 3.6+.  See this article for more detail: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-asynchronous-logging/

Comment: No need to add a log4j2 file. Mule will use a perfectly valid default configuration if you don't add it.

Comment: @ashosborne1 if you get a chance can you please take a look at another mule related question i have posted.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the console should be already present on the log directory in two different files. One for the mule logs itself and another one for your app's log.

Comment: Romero There are log files like tx1.log tx2.log - but the contents are unreadable - LEÅçìø¹1çìø¹52 THOMAS STREET              
APT 3B
Šçìø¹3 çìø¹4çìø¹

Š   ,çìø¹ çìø¹çìø¹0707°çìø¹ çìø¹  çìø¹
 çìø¹çìø¹500Ëçìø¹çìø¹NÊçìø¹
çìø¹‚Eçìø¹ çìø¹çìø¹500Ëçìø¹çìø¹‚Nçìø¹ çìø¹ªØí çìø¹çìø¹NÊçìø¹çìø¹UÓçìø¹çìø¹

Comment: you are looking at the wrong directory. Don look at .mule, but rather at MULE_HOME/logs

Answer (score 0):

In case if we need to update the properties file directly 
(log4j.properties). below will serve the purpose.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, default.out, default.file 

log4j.appender.default.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.out.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=\\Desktop\\Mule.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```